Error al realizar la conexión de un archivo accdb (MS Access) con pyodbc en Google Colab
¡Buenas noches colegas !
Por favor, agradeceré  su enorme ayuda y orientación con este problema:
Al querer realizar una conexión a un archivo Access (formato accdb), cargado previamente en Google Colab, con pyodbc me arroja el siguiente error ⚡:
Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (.mdb, .accdb)' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Librerías instaladas: python 3.10, pyodbc 5.1.0 y pandas 2.0.3
Nombre del controlador: DRIVER_NAME = "Microsoft Access Driver (.mdb, .accdb)"
Ruta del archivo en Google Colab: DB_PATH = r'\content\dataset.accdb'
Establecer la conexión: conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={%s};DBQ=%s;" % (DRIVER_NAME, DB_PATH))

De antemano, cualquier comentario con alguna idea u orientación para poder realizar la conexión desde Google Colab, será bienvenida .
Nota: Desde VSCode con archivo local funciona 100%.
